# Ausdruckqualität oder Ausdrucksqualität im Sinne der Qualität eines von einem Drucker hergestellten Dokuments

Tags: noun, compound

> Bei schlechter Ausdruckqualität sind die kleinen zentrierten Punkte · (U+00B7) womöglich nicht lesbar.

Oder bei schlechter Ausdruck**s**qualität?  Es geht hier also um die Güte der Ausgabe eines Printers, auf gut Denglisch.

Vorsicht bei Wortzählungen von G**gle oder in sonstigen Korpora: „Ausdruck(s)qualität“ kann auch

- die Güte eines natürlichsprachlichen Terms oder aber auch
- die Güte der Wortwahl einer Person bedeuten.

Die drei Bedeutungen können (müssen aber nicht) einen unterschiedlichen Fugen-s-Gebrauch aufweisen.

Für die Leute, die beim Lesen so ihre Schwierigkeiten haben: Wenn ich „Druckqualität“ und nicht „Ausdruckqualität“ gemeint hätte, hätte ich es auch so geschrieben!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127657/discussion-on-question-by-geekestgeek-ausdruckqualitat-oder-ausdrucksqualitat-im).

Answer (score 5):

"Ausdruck(s)qualität" ist kein Wort, das man in Wörterbüchern finden würde, es ist eine Ad-Hoc-Wortschöpfung. Das ist ja im Deutschen ohne weiteres möglich, wenn sich der Sinn für den Leser erschließt. Und als Wortschöpfung sind beide möglich, sowohl Ausdruckqualität als auch Ausdrucksqualität, zumal sich der erste Teil entweder auf das Ausdrucken als Aktion oder auf den Ausdruck als sein Ergebnis beziehen kann.

"Ausdruck" ist ein Wort mit vielen Bedeutungen. Ich würde wahrscheinlich versuchen, eine Wortschöpfung zu vermeiden, die nur in ihrem unmittelbaren Kontext verständlich ist. Wenn es keinen guten Gründe gibt, ein neues Wort einzuführen, würde ich es mit Genitiv als *Qualität des Ausdrucks* formulieren oder je nach Kontext einfach das eingeführte Wort *Druckqualität* benutzen. Das ist aber natürlich Geschmackssache.

Comment: Das Deutsche lässt, wie ein Lego-Baukasten, Zusammensetzungen zu. Es gibt unendlich viele gültige Wörter, die man weder im Duden noch im Wahrig findet, zum Beispiel *fünfhundertfünfundfünfzig*.

Comment: @GeekestGeek: Ja, genau wie oben geschrieben, es ist problemlos möglich, das Wort selbst zusammenzusetzen. Und deswegen kannst du auch selbst entscheiden, ob du dabei ein Fugen-s benutzen möchtest oder nicht. Ist das missverständlich formuliert?

Comment: Du meintest „Ad-Hoc-Wortschöpfung“. Das stimmt nicht. Oder du müsstest dann  *fünfhundertfünfundfünfzig* und zig Wörter auf *-qualität*, die nicht im Lexikon stehen (*Hausqualität*, *Wohnungsqualität*, *Bushaltestellenqualität*, …) zu angeblichen „Ad-Hoc-Wortschöpfungen“ erklären. Ob man ein Kompositum in Wörterbüchern findet oder nicht, ist nur dann relevant, wenn ein Bedeutungswandel stattfand, also, um beim unseren Beispiel zu bleiben, wenn „Ausdruck(s)qualität” nicht oder nicht ganz „Qualität des/eines Audrucks“ bedeuten würde, oder wenn von einer Fugen-Regel abgewichen wurde.

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, was dich an dem Wort Ad-Hoc-Wortschöpfung stört, wenn du selbst sagst, dass es unendlich viele gültige Wörter gibt. Das bedeutet ja nur, dass man sie zusammensetzt, wenn man sie braucht. Das gilt für alle deine Beispiele à la *Bushaltestellenqualität*, außer für die Zahlen, die ja nach festen Regeln gebildet werden, die man in der Tat nachschlagen kann, da gibt es keine Freiheit der Wortbildung.
Wenn so ein Wort wie "Ausdruckqualität" in einem bestimmten Bereich oft benutzt wird, ist er irgendwann ein eingeführter Ausdruck und taucht dann auch in Wörterbüchern auf.

Answer (score 0):

Das 's' wäre ein Fugenlaut, der in einer Komposition verwendet werden **kann**. Wie schon in den Kommentaren erwähnt, ist deine Komposition nicht glücklich gewählt aber auch nicht unerlaubt.

Ein klare Regel für die Verwendung eines Fugenlautes gibt es leider nicht und ist zudem regional verschieden. Es gibt viele Beispiele für solche Kompositionen, mal mit oder mal ohne Fugenlaut. Der folgende Wikipediaartikel gibt eine sehr gute Übersicht: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut

Besonders interessant finde ich diesen Absatz: "Zu Beginn des 19. Jahrhunderts regte der Schriftsteller Jean Paul an, das Fugen-s solle abgeschafft werden, denn er hielt den s-Laut für unschön und erachtete das Fugen-s für unregelmäßig und unnötig. Also ließ er in den späteren Ausgaben seiner Werke alle Fugen-s eliminieren. Sein Vorhaben stieß auf massiven Widerstand der Brüder Grimm, die das Fugen-s als einen historisch gewachsenen Bestandteil der deutschen Sprache verteidigten."

Dem würde ich mich anschließen, im Zweifel sollte auf ein **s** eher verzichtet werden. ;-)